# Android: How to get USB PID and VID of Android device

Tags: android, usb, pid

I am developing an android application and I have a problem with determining a USB PID and VID of android device where the app is installed. I found some tutorials how to get PID and VID of connected devices but this is not what I need. I was also looking for it in Android SDK but I didn't found any mention about it.

Thank you very much for any help !

Comment: do you have a error or what??what is the problem

Comment: I don't have an error. I just need to know how to get the USB PID and VID (as said in title). I am looking for some library or Android SDK functionality which can determine this values.

Comment: Afaik there is no fixed combination for a device. I know that HTC have different PIDs for a mass storage connection, tethering, debugging etc. Can you provide some more details for which purpose you need an VID/PID combination?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. I need PID which is used for mass storage connection. My PC application is synchronized with Android app when connected as mass storage or MTP via USB. My PC app has stored all PIDs of synced device. But I am implementing also wireless sync, where I need to get the same PID for pairing. Thank you for your comments !